# Printing the records one below the other

Tags: c

I want to print data like this :

```
FirstName FamilyName (33 characters), Tel: xxxxxxxxxx, Age: xx, Level: xx, Salary: xxxxx.xx
```

For example

```
John Dilbert Tel: 6135202600, Age: 58, Level: 13, Salary:    450.34
Jane Smith   Tel: 6135202600, Age: 47, Level: 10, Salary: 133450.00
```

Main problem am facing is how to put Tel: one before the other . Also how to format the floating salary such that decimal comes one below the other.

Currently my output look like this :

```
John Dilbert Tel: 6135202600, Age: 58, Level: 13, Salary: 450.34
Jane Smith Tel: 6135202600, Age: 47, Level: 10, Salary: 133450.00
```

Code :

```
void printData(struct person currentPerson){
    printf("%s %-33sTel: %10s",currentPerson.firstName,currentPerson.familyName,currentPerson.telephone);

}
void printStudent(struct Student currentStudent){
    printf("GPA:%3d, Courses:%3d, Tuition: %5f\n",currentStudent.GPA,currentStudent.coursesCount,currentStudent.tuitionFees);
}
```

In main:

```
printData(person[i]);
printf(", ");
printStudent(person[i].student);
```

But still result is wrong. Why ? Please help

Comment: @JohnKugelman What about after family name there will be different space count because of size difference of string

Comment: @JohnKugelman I added code. But still results are not one below other

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the width of your data, then you could use the width sub-specifiers in the printf format string. Eg. :

```
printf("%5d", 2);
```

Comment: what about last double value ?

Comment: What about after family name there will be different space count because of size difference of string